# Setting FontSize below 6 in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, textbox, font-size

Whenever I set a TextBox's `FontSize` dependency property to a value less than 6.0, whether in XAML or in code, an ArgumentException is thrown. Is there any way to work around this arbitrary limit?

Comment: Just for curiosity- why would you want to do that?

Comment: Long story short, it's used in a diagram in which node captions are not necessarily legible at the default zoom level, but are legible when the user zooms in. For me, this is a matter of being able to change one value (the font size) versus having to resize everything else in order to accommodate the 6 pt minimum.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is a practical one as Pixel fonts are not natively supported and almost all fonts look rubbish at less than 6pt (as they are rendered anti-aliased).

**Two options**:

- *You can apply scaling to the text object* if you insist on going
  smaller than 6pt,
- but I would suggest *using actual
  Pixel Fonts for finer work*.

Have a look at this answer. "Koistya Navin" has actual code that works a treat rendering his pixel font (code available via links on the question):
[Pixel fonts in Silverlight 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567671/pixel-fonts-in-silverlight-4)

Hope this helps.